# How can i add a link on a specific point of the image?

Tags: image, css

I have the following image and i want to add a link on the basket icon. How is that possible?

[image]

Thanks for your answers. Now  i have two ways to do this or with **html**:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<p style="font-weight:normal;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFD700;background-color:#000000;border: 5px ridge #ababab;letter-spacing:4pt;word-spacing:-3pt;font-size:42px;text-align:center;font-family:georgia, serif;line-height:4;margin:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;height:183px;">New Online Shop <a href="https://frix-cy.com/shop/"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart " aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

</p>
```

Or with @blue answer using html [shape attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_shape.asp) on the image:

```html
 <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I8q6.jpg' width='500' height='150' usemap='#basket' />
    <map name='basket'>
        <area shape='rect' coords='440 50 500 100' href='www.your_link.com' alt='basket_icon' />
    </map>
    <p>Click on the basket</p>
```

Comment: i think you look for something like https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp. here you define points on the image and make them clickable.

Comment: It could be more interesting to have the text as a text and the icon as an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use **map and area** to select specific *areas* on an image

The **HTML**

```html
   <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I8q6.jpg' width='500' height='150' usemap='#basket' />
    <map name='basket'>
        <area shape='rect' coords='440 50 500 100' href='www.your_link.com' alt='basket_icon' />
    </map>
    <p>Click on the basket</p>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: use editor to show your code in a runtime environment (`control+M`)

Comment: great! how do you calculate the coords?

Comment: @csandreas1 Just by hit-and-trial ;D